# OSX, Looking for some solutions for viewing my Outlook XP messages?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, microsoft-outlook, seamonkey

I'm gradually trying to move over to my mac mini, from my Windows XP machine. I'm using Seamonkey. However I have a couple of PST files around 200mb each.

All I really need is to be able to search through my emails and copy and paste. **So I don't really need to import the messages into Seamonkey.**

I did think if I could export my messages, into folders and files, mirroring the layout of my PST files, might work. But I can't find a way to do this.

So I'm looking for a solution / suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import PST Files into Seamonkey by following [this link.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files) It should work for Seamonkey as it does for Thunderbird. I do recommend Firefox and Thunderbird over Seamonkey, but if that's what you like, go for it.

Comment: Hmm.. the page mainly offers a Howto for Windows. The OS X part itself is not that clear, it only includes some links to commercial software, et cetera. If you know of one solution that works, it'd be best if you put that in your answer.

Comment: The 9 steps at the top seemed to be within reason. I am going to test it myself in a moment

Comment: I don't really want to import.